# attempt to create apple like shopping cart page (price updates based on customization selections)

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to make a cart page where based on each selection the price updates as you see on this page
http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/configure/MC915LL/A?mco=MTk4Mjc2MDA

if you notice on the apple page that each radio fields value has a number like 095-344 and this value is some how sent via ajax to a serverside who then receives a price value to be added to the cart as a total that is viewed.

i created something similar here is the link.
http://69.231.228.101:8888/demo/

i have made only the first two fields to work which is quantity and type. when the page loads the 3rd option is auto selected and its price is displayed. and when the section select is selected the items value is accumulated to the value that already exists in the upper right. the problem im having is if you now select the quantity again to change the amount of quantity you wanted the value resets instead of do the right math. what am i doing wrong?

plus, would you know of a jquery site or some site that has attempted this that i can study? i have looked long and hard and cannot find anything of this kind created. i just see a bunch of simple cart calculation pages and nothing like what im looking for. alot of sites have something like this that im looking for for example apple, dell, hp, for product customizations and the price updates based on your selection. what im wondering how and where did they learn how to do it. there must be a site that teaches it.

thanks

Comment: Could you please post the server side code

Comment: here is the server side for ajax.php: http://pastie.org/1406299

Comment: Cannot load the demo. I have an idea but i'd like to first see what have you done. So please let me see the demo. And most of all, wait at least 5 days before re-asking the same question. SO doesn't love this kind of things.

Comment: sorry about that here you go. http://69.231.228.101:8888/demo/

Comment: I need to see the entire script, not just a $_GET manager. (You better check if $_GET vars are empty or == '' with empty(), anyway).

Comment: here is the ajax.php on pastie. http://pastie.org/1406299

Comment: Price should be integer also, so that you can add and subtract. I'm working on it.

Comment: thanks, ill give u all the possible points i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ok. Try this: Take your form and submit it. (If you weren't doing it then, do it) with ajax (Look at [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)). In this way every checked radio is submitted. Now take each radio and check his value adding to a variable `$priceNUM` the right price value. At the end add every single price from every single checked radio together, into a `$total` var and output that.
Here's a stupid example.

HTML

```
<form>
 <input type="radio" name="box1" value="01"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box1" value="03"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box1" value="03"/>

 <input type="radio" name="box2" value="01"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box2" value="03"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box2" value="03"/>

 <input type="radio" name="box3" value="01"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box3" value="03"/>
 <input type="radio" name="box3" value="03"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

# Requiring vars
$box1 = $_POST['box1'];
$box2 = $_POST['box2'];
$box3 = $_POST['box3'];

# Checking
if (empty($box1) or empty($box2) or empty($box3)) { /* Error, or $price = 0 */ }

switch ($box1) 
{
 case '01':
  $price1 = 10;
 break;

 case '02':
  $price1 = 20;
 break;

 case '03':
  $price1 = 30;
 break;

 default:
  $price1 = 0;
 break;
}

switch ($box2) 
{
 case '01':
  $price2 = 50;
 break;

 case '02':
  $price2 = 100;
 break;

 case '03':
  $price2 = 150;
 break;

 default:
  $price2 = 0;
 break;
}

switch ($box3) 
{
 case '01':
  $price3 = 2;
 break;

 case '02':
  $price3 = 4;
 break;

 case '03':
  $price3 = 6;
 break;

 default:
  $price3 = 0;
 break;
}

$total = $price1 + $price2 + $price3;
echo $total;
```

?>

Now with jquery make the form to submit when a box is changed (i think you already know how to do this) and we are done.

Actually every time it happens, we are going to calculate the total, but it is the easiest way. You could also make something with a database or with cookies but it became too complicated.

Comment: thanks for your post but the problem im having if you check the (script.js file ) when i select the second selection more than 2 times the calculated val goes up.

Comment: Yep, that's because of the ajax.php script. You have to calculate the total not just check the product id. You have to submit the form and make a total of each radio (checkbox, or menu) and return that. I'm not really great in javascript and jquery, but i think the real problem is in your ajax.php file. Try my example and let me know. Else i'll found out another solution...

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured it out. i cant believe i didnt see this before. all i had to do was assign the selected value for each selection into its own variable. then have a function on the very end that grabs each value from each select then displays it.

```
var qprice;
var typeprice;


$(document).ready(function() {


        /* -----------------------------------------------------
                Quantity Selection
           ----------------------------------------------------- */

        $("#quantity").change(function() 
        {
            var hash = $("#quantity").val(); //returns 0001 (ex)



            $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },

            function(data)
            {
                qprice = data.price;
                displayPrice();
            }, "json");
        });




        /* -----------------------------------------------------
                Type Selection
           ----------------------------------------------------- */
        $("#type").change(function() 
        {
            var hash = $("#type").val(); //returns 0001 (ex)


            $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },

            function(data)
            {   
                typeprice = data.price
                displayPrice();
                //$("#price").attr({value: total});

            }, "json");
        });








        function displayPrice() 
        {
            total = parseInt(qprice) + parseInt(typeprice);
            alert(total);
        }


});
```

i just have to enter all the other checks so that i dont get undefined errors. charlie i love u, u inspired me to figure it out.